# How to modiffy output by adding name1.name 2.... in all output of python

Tags: javascript, java, python, data-structures

to write a code that take input such as

```
123,143,531,431
```

and gives output

```
{"number1":"123","number2":"143","number3":"531","number4":"431"}
```

any language among java and python can help 
for python i tried

```
data = "123,143,531,431"

x = data.split(", ")

print(x)
```

and help for java would do too or javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can use dict comprehension to create the dictionary in your desired format, to learn more about dict comprehensions in python refer [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). Here, we also used the `enumerate` function, to learn more about this function refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Use:

```
x = {f"number{i}": v for i, v in enumerate(data.split(","), 1)}
print(x)
```

This prints:

```
{'number1': '123', 'number2': '143', 'number3': '531', 'number4': '431'}
```

---

Update (To get double quotes instead of single):

```
import json

print(json.dumps(x))
```

This prints:

```
{"number1": "123", "number2": "143", "number3": "531", "number4": "431"}
```

Comment: x = {f"number{i}": v for i, v in enumerate(data.split(","), 1)}                                                                                                      
                    ^                                                                                                                                                    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @VaibhavMishra I think you are using python 2+ replace `f"number{i}"` with `"number{}".format(i)`

Comment: how to get double quotes instead of single using this

Comment: @VaibhavMishra Its just a representation but if you still want to do check the edited answer.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra Nope. But i think this might work, `x = data.split(",")

res = {}
for (i = 1; i <= x.length; i++){
    res["number" + i] = x[i - 1]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))`

Answer (score 0):

```
d=dict()
for i in range(1,len(x)+1):
    d['number'+str(i)]=x[i-1]
print(d)
```

nothing to explain...

Comment: add explanation to prevent removal of question by bots.

Comment: It would be nice to explain what is going on so as other people can adapt your answer, because maybe the question is only a simplified version of the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension to achieve your goal:

```
x = data.split(",")
result = {f"Number {ind}": x[ind] for ind in range(len(x))}
```

This will give you:

```
{'Number 0': '123', 'Number 1': '143', 'Number 2': '531', 'Number 3': '431'}
```

Comment: result = {f "Number {ind}": x[ind] for ind in range(len(x))}                                                                                                         
                             ^                                                                                                                                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Java solution using a simple for loop. Store the data in a String Array splitting the elements on the ",". Then loop through elements and format output as required.

```
String data = "123,143,531,431";

String[] splitString = data.split(",");

for(int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i ++)
{
    if(i == splitString.length - 1)
        System.out.print("Number " + (i + 1) + ": " + splitString[i]);

    else
        System.out.print("Number " + (i + 1) + ": " + splitString[i] + ", ");
}
```

}